# Issue with printing query as csv

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have this query here and this is the way i output it to a csv, someone could help me please?
It's messy there, and it's be better if i printed it as an Excel, and i tried some versions, but the fact that i'm using odbc query makes it a little hard for me to adapt it with the samples i've found online.

```
$result = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET,SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,
SMS_MONTIME.time_added FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE 
forma.data_fillim >= '$df' AND forma.data_fillim <= '$dm' ORDER BY forma.id DESC"; 
$user_query = odbc_exec($connection, $result) or die(odbc_error());
//While loop to fetch the records
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($user_query))
{
$contents.=$row['klienti'].",";
$contents.=$row['id'].",";
$contents.=$row['tekniku_emer'].",";
$contents.=$row['telefoni'].",";
$contents.=$row['data_fillim'].",";
$contents.=$row['difekti'].",";
$contents.=$row['tekniku_mesazh'].",";
$contents.=$row['shenime'].",";

}

// remove html and php tags etc.
$contents = strip_tags($contents); 

//header to make force download the file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Kondicioner".date('d-m-Y').".csv");
print $contents;
```

Comment: Besides the fact that it would be a lot easier if you used PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to write each row as a CSV file line.... what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The issue is, when i open the csv nothing is at it's place, the rows are messed up, they're not separated..

Comment: You're not putting a return at the end of each line.... use fputcsv() and you don't need to worry about that, or about columns retrieved from your database that contain commas, or any of the myriad of other potential problems you're not checking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to output csv is to use the fputcsv function..

```
<?php
$result = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET,SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,
SMS_MONTIME.time_added FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE 
forma.data_fillim >= '$df' AND forma.data_fillim <= '$dm' ORDER BY forma.id DESC"; 
$user_query = odbc_exec($connection, $result) or die(odbc_error());
//While loop to fetch the records
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='Kondicioner".date('d-m-Y').".csv'");
$fp = fopen("php://output","w");
// here you set up your header
fputcsv($fp, array("klienti","id","tekniku_emer","telefoni","data_fillim","difekti","tekniku_mesazh", "shenime");
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($user_query))
{
   $row = array_map("strip_tags", $row);
   fputcsv($fp, array($row['klienti'],$row['id'],
                      $row['tekniku_emer'],$row['telefoni'],
                      $row['data_fillim'],$row['difekti'],
                      $row['tekniku_mesazh'],$row['shenime']));

}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please i get this error: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback  function 'striptags' not found or invalid function name in E:\wamp\www\montim\montime-bcp\montime\vendosja-porosise\download-all\index.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>     
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>

Comment: sorry... it's strip_tags not striptags

Comment: Better this way `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='Kondicioner" . date('d-m-Y') . ".csv'");` filename enclosed in quotes

Comment: That's great, thanks :)
if i don't bother, could you please tell me, how could i format this in such a way that i have a header and the info to be in columns... without needing to import the file in order to achieve that..

Comment: @Alb.. Just did ... its more of the same ... you can change the values in the call there to be more Human Friendly :)